# MSAL iOS not able reuse Accesstoken and cookies for WKwebview

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

Not able to share cookies between MSAL library to WkWebview.

I have used MSALlibrary for authentication in the iOS app, In the app, there are few functionalities that were not implemented in iOS so, we are navigating to the web application(using WKWebview) where it asks every time login prompt.

Can I send access token/cookies or do something so will not ask for authentication the second time when I open WKWebView?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Divakar, I'm facing same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

For iOS **ASWebAuthenticationSession**, **SFAuthenticationSession**, and **SFSafariViewController** are considered system browsers. For macOS only **ASWebAuthenticationSession** is available. In general, system browsers share cookies and other website data with the Safari browser application.
By default, MSAL will dynamically detect iOS version and select the recommended system browser available on that version. On iOS 12+ it will be **ASWebAuthenticationSession**.

When you verify user via API, you must get the token from response. Pass this token as a query parameter in your url and redirect to Safari.

URL - `https://www.example.com/page1`

URL with token - `https://www.example.com/page1?token=asdfv12324fvfropfc23as`

You can store the token in **localStorage/Cookies**.

Read more [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-python/wiki).